# Weird "File Format not Supported" error for a CSV file (under a new event) when ingesting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I just finished successfully testing file ingestion (dropping a CSV file on S3 bucket and extracting the data into a dynamo table) for a new event that I added, In order to
perform this I had to:

**1)** Create the following new **SMB** event filter on S3 bucket dev-caa-cxx-ci2 under Properties ->  Event notifications:

- data/landing/vendor/SMB/customerlink/sftp/leads/new/

**2)** Next I added the following environment variables for my Lambada  code to use:

- data/landing/vendor/SMB/customerlink/sftp/leads/processed/ (i.e. CSV_PROCESSED_SMB variable)
- data/landing/vendor/SMB/customerlink/sftp/leads/error/  (i.e. CSV_ERROR_FOLDER_SMB variable)
- data/landing/vendor/SMB/customerlink/sftp/leads/new// (i.e. CSV_NEW_FOLDER_SMB variable)

**3)** Next, I updated the S3 – Dynamo Lambda to add the environment variables to the  function that loads the extracted file data into a vendor sftp in the dynamo table.

**The file ingestion for development worked well using the previous setup for that dev-caa-cxx-ci2  bucket.**

However, I did the same process setup for  S3 bucket **test-caa-cxx-ci2**  but I get the following error:

**File Format not Supported for data/landing/vendor/SMB/customerlink/sftp/leads/new/CL_Ex__Customers_Veronica_Test.csv**

Based on the setup between the 2 buckets and their environment variables and events, everything is identical. *TThe files are CSV files and they've always ingested in the past*

**Note**: for the other ingestions on bucket **test-caa-cxx-ci2** which did not use the new **SMB** event , all the files had ingested OK and were successfully processed.
Here's a snippet of the code.  The Code appears to die at the first else-if statement - the previous print statement before the IF statement prints out but nothing afterward (it should print that ***'in SMB parse_csv'*** statement:

```
print(os.environ['CSV_NEW_FOLDER'])
    if os.environ['CSV_NEW_FOLDER'] in event['file_path']:
        print('in Customer Link parse_csv')
        parse_csv_func = parse_customerlink(event, obj)
            #Checks if parse_csv return empty dictionary
        if parse_csv_func:
            parse_flag = True
            new_folder_path = os.environ['CSV_NEW_FOLDER']
            processed_folder_path = os.environ['CSV_PROCESSED_FOLDER']
    elif os.environ['CSV_NEW_FOLDER_SMB'] in event['file_path']:
        print('in SMB parse_csv')
        parse_csv_func =parse_customerlink_smb(event, obj)
            #Checks if parse_csv return empty dictionary
        if parse_csv_func:
            parse_flag = True
            new_folder_path = os.environ['CSV_NEW_FOLDER_SMB']
            processed_folder_path = os.environ['CSV_PROCESSED_FOLDER_SMB']
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include the first few lines of the CSV that you're getting the error with?

Answer (score 0):

OK after working long hours and on multiple projects (This is embarrassing!), it occurred to me that **I forgot to upload the updated python code into the lambda** function for this S3 bucket when I thought I had done so. After ingesting the files again they all processed successfully. This! after painstakingly verifying that all the even filters and environment variables matched what was in AWS Dev and prepping the csv data files to make sure they would test. This is one of those love-hate solutions: you're relieved when it's that simple but it ticks you off that you didn't spot the easy solution earlier.  Thanks everyone and sorry about that!